# Rust Match Struct Attribute in Method Fails Borrow Checker

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, borrow-checker

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum E {
    Foo(u32),
    Bar,
    Baz
}

struct S { a: E }

impl S {
    fn print(&self) {
        match self.a {
            E::Foo(a) => println!("{}", a),
            e => println!("{:?}", e)
        }
    }
}


fn main() {
    let a = S { a: E::Bar };
    a.print();
}
```

This clip fails to compile:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
  --> main.rs:11:15
   |
11 |         match self.a {
   |               ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
12 |            E::Foo(a) => println!("{}", a),
13 |            e => println!("{:?}", e)
   |            - hint: to prevent move, use `ref e` or `ref mut e`
```

and I more or less understand why: `self` owns `self.a`, and because I only borrowed `self` in the method declaration, I can't move `self.a` out of `self`.  But I can't figure out what the best approach to fix this is.  Obviously I could use `ref e => println!("{:?}", e)` in this contrived example, but I'm looking for a more general description where I can't use a pointer.  Do I have to copy `self.a` in the match statement?  This would seem wasteful if there was a separate case for `E::Baz`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use a pointer/reference?

Comment: You can also use `match &self.a` combined with `&E::Foo(a) => ...`.

Comment: @wimh that only works in *this* case because `a` has the type `u32` which implements `Copy`.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson say if you wanted to return a boxed e at the end of the function that will outlive self

Comment: @cderwin Then copy it (if needed) at the point you return or `Box` it, rather than when matching.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson if I do that then I can't call any mutable methods on self (for good reason).  I think the way I need to do this is through something like `match self.a { ref e => e.clone() }`.  Thanks for the suggestion of just cloning it.

Comment: This was in a &self method so you couldn't call mutable methods anyway.  :-)

Comment: You can also match on `E::Foo(ref a) => ...` which will also work for non copy types